# AWS Lightsail can't update Route53 for Let'sEncrypt certs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to get Let's Encrypt automatic cert update on a AWS Lightsail wordpress instance and Route53.

I used [these official instructions](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress) for adding a SSL certs to a AWS Lightsail wordpress website.

Site SSL is working fine, but I was looking for a way to automate the re-issue and found the certbot plugin - [certbot-dns-route53](https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

I created a separate AWS non-admin user just for the updates, and added the policy as suggested by the certbot official docs

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "certbot-dns-route53 sample policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:GetChange"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Action" : [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource" : [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/MYZONEID"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I placed the API access information in both a environment variable and ~/.aws.config file.

I executed the command -

```
    sudo certbot certonly --dns-route53 --dns-route53-propagation-seconds 30 --dry-run -d 'domain.
com,*.domain.com'
```

And I get the following error -

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListHostedZones
> operation: User: arn:aws:sts::548507530525:assumed-role/Amaz
> onLightsailInstanceRole/i-00ff79ff762ac0576 is not authorized to
> perform: route53:ListHostedZones To use certbot-dns-route53, configure
> credentials as described at
> https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.h
> tml#best-practices-for-configuring-credentials and add the necessary
> permissions for Route53 access

I attempted a ~.aws/config & credentials file as well  -

config-

```
[profile cross-account]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:user/domain_cert_update
source_profile=default
```

credentials -

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=ACCESSKEY
aws_secret_access_key=SECRETKEYHERE
```

I'm not sure how to get the lightsail instance of /i-00ff79ff762ac0576 assigned to the policy correctly.  I've read through the config guide it links and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question, it pointed me in the right direction to get this working myself.

I created the AWS CLI config files in the home directory at `/home/bitnami/.aws`. For me the issue was `certbot` wasn't actually finding these config files as it was looking in the root directory instead of the home directory.

I added a link using the root user:

```
sudo -s
ln -s /home/bitnami/.aws/ ~/.aws
```

After that `certbot` could find the config files and the command was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-enabling-https-on-wordpress

If you use Certbot, you should renew license manually. But use the above tutorial and you can setup HTTPS by using bncert tool.

I have setup HTTPS and Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on 2 of my websites using the above documentation.